# What does it mean if you put more that one static modifier before a variable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I was just fooling around in Xcode and I discovered that the following statement compiles and it doesn't even raise a warning let alone an error:

```
static static static int static long static var[5];
```

What's up with that? Does this make it super-DUPER static? :)

All joking aside, why does the compiler permit repeating the static modifier? Is there actually a reason to allow people to do this or were the people who wrote the compiler too lazy to make this raise an error?

Comment: Definitely going to start declaring things like this

Comment: I know...right! It will make the code more maintainable also. Future developers won't have to hunt to try to find out if a variable is `static` or not. The answer will be right in front of them!

Comment: Lol I tried in C and got `Untitled.c:4:36: error: cannot combine with previous 'float' declaration specifier
        static static static float static int static x = 2;`

Comment: @iBlue saying `int long` is the same as saying `long int`, which is a valid type. The question is really about the number of `static`s, not the ability to declare an `int long` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an Objective-C developer, but does the language allow for an arbitrary ordering of modifiers (e.g. static volatile extern)? If so, then it's probably a benign bug in the compiler that after reading a modifier ("`static`" in this case) returns to a state where it accepts any modifier terminal again, and will do until it encounters the variable's type. Continual `static` declarations wouldn't contradict any prior modifiers so it wouldn't raise any errors; so based on this I would expect `volatile volatile volatile int x;` to also work.

Comment: Yeah, likely `static` just sets the corresponding flag in the definition, and at the end of reading it it's checked for conflicts like `static register`.  No checking is done for duplicate modifiers (except, I suppose, such monstrosities as `long long`).

Comment: Yup, you're right...`volatile volatile volatile int x;` does indeed work

Comment: Wow, not bad for someone who'se never written a single keystroke of Objective-C in his life :)

Answer (score 2):

For C 2011, The following applies:

> **Section 6.7.1 Paragraph 2**
>
> At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration specifiers in a declaration, except that `_Thread_local` may appear with static or extern.

And storage class specifiers are defined as:

```
storage-class-specifier:
          typedef 
          extern
          static
          _Thread_local
          auto
          register
```

So for C 2011, that should be illegal.

---

*As to Objective C, I have no idea where to find a language specification, so I can't help you there.*

Comment: The specification (unfortunately) is the compiler's source code, although all the straight-C parts are _supposed_ to be the same as C.